# Are companies listed on Euronext Growth and Euronext Access required to publish financial statements?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, european-union, france, financial-statements

Companies listed on the Euronext stock exchanges are classified into "Euronext", "Euronext Growth" (formerly known as Alternext), and "Euronext Access" (formerly known as [marché libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/March%C3%A9_libre)). These appear to be different markets for large/mid-cap, mid/small-cap, and nano-cap stocks respectively. The "Euronext" market is the most strictly regulated market, followed by "Euronext Growth" and "Euronext Access". The question is: do companies listed on "Euronext Growth" and "Euronext Access" have to publish their financial results on a regular basis, or can they keep their financial statements private?

I am asking this question because in the US stock market, some OTC-traded stocks are legally able to "go dark" and stop publishing financial statements. I am wondering if this is also the case in the European markets that Euronext operates in (especially France, because among all the Euronext exchanges, Euronext Paris has the largest number of companies listed on "Euronext Growth" and "Euronext Access").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are companies listed on Euronext Growth and Euronext Access required to publish financial statements?

Yes. Although the specific disclosure requirements differ between Euronext Growth and Euronext Access, all companies are required to publish financial statements on a regular basis.

On Euronext's [Choosing your Market](https://www.euronext.com/en/raise-capital/how-go-public/choosing-market) webpage, there are helpful tables that summarize the ongoing obligations of companies that list on Euronext's markets. Here are the relevant parts about the ongoing disclosure requirements:

|  | Euronext Access | Euronext Access+ | Euronext Growth | Euronext |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Financial reporting: annual | Annual financial statements (unaudited) | Annual financial statements (audited) | Annual financial report (annual financial statements, business report and auditor’s report on annual financial statements) | Annual financial report (annual financial statements, business report and auditor’s report on annual financial statements) |
| Financial reporting: semi-annual | Not required | Semi-annual financial statements (unaudited) | Semi-annual financial statements and business report (unaudited) | Semi-annual financial statements with auditor’s limited review, business report |
| Accounting standards | IFRS or local GAAP | IFRS or local GAAP | IFRS or local GAAP | IFRS |
| Financial/Investor Website | Yes | Yes | Yes Not required for Oslo | Yes |
| Market Abuse Regime (inside information, insider lists and declaration of management transactions) | Applicable | Applicable | Applicable | Applicable |
| Disclosure of threshold crossing (capital or voting rights) | Not applicable | Not applicable | Applicable | Applicable |